# unable to load local html file in swift 4

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

Always storing nil in the filepath i have my html file in the project root directory

```
let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
           self.view.addSubview(myWebView) 

        do {
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iphone_help", ofType: "html")
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }            
            let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
        }

        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
```

Comment: Could you show your Error ?

Comment: no errors but always storing nil inthe file path

Comment: i have to add my html file by using build phases

Answer (score 0):

```
 func loadWebView(htmlString : String) {
        //Give HTML file a name:
        //Constants.kTempFiled

        let htmlFileName: NSString =  "file.html"

        //Create a reference to the temporary directory that will store the HTML file:
        let tempDirectory: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

        //Append reference temporary directory to include HTML file name:
        let htmlFilePath: NSString = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(htmlFileName as String) as NSString as NSString

        //Convert appended temporary directory NSString to an NSURL object:
        let htmlUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: htmlFilePath as String)


        //Below, HTML string is written to a file:
        do { try htmlString.write(toFile: htmlFilePath as String, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) }
        catch { }

        //HTML file URL is fetched and displayed in UIWebView:
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: htmlUrl))

    }
```